# Getting SDL to work on OSX with C++ entry point

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, opengl, sdl

I have a system for building my software already set up, using a makefile and command-line tools.

I have been easily able to modify the makefile to support my Mac (10.7.4 now), so I am trying to get my code to work independently of XCode. I'll deal with XCode once I start porting stuff to iOS. My hope is that a makefile solution (while my codebase is still manageable by said makefile) allows me better options for portability and automation.

I am experiencing exactly what is described [here](http://graphicsnotes.blogspot.com/2010/01/programmatically-creating-window-in-mac.html). The code compiles and problems are encountered on run-time.

At first I was using the SDL framework (`-framework SDL`) from the binary download on the SDL site, so I figured I could fix the problem by properly building SDL from source. I have done this and am now linking to `libSDL.a` and `libSDLMain.a`. This in turn requires me to include these additional frameworks to successfully compile (I came up with the list based on the output of `sdl-config --static-libs`:

```
-framework Cocoa -framework IOKit -framework AudioToolbox -framework AudioUnit -framework Carbon -framework ApplicationServices
```

However I still have the same problem, which the article explains has to do with missing this:

```
[NSApplication sharedApplication];
```

My code has no Obj-C code. I'm happy to plug some Obj-C into it, though. I added `SDLMain.m` that came with one of the packages but the linker has a problem with that: `ld: duplicate symbol _main`

Okay, so I'm not gonna get away with that so easy.

What's the little piece I'm missing that will let me initialize my NSApplication? Is there a way to do it without having a separate source file (from my `Main.cpp`) which must now be Obj-C? Is there some C/C++ wrapper function that I can call `sharedApplication` with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of credit should go to RavuAlHemio because he pointed out for me enough information about what SDL is doing (trying to do) with the entry point. I then edited my code slightly, from

```
#undef main
int main(int argc,char *argv[]) {
```

to

```
int main(int argc,char *argv[]) {
```

The only reason I had it the first way was because on Windows via MinGW (but not Linux) stdout and stderr were redirected to files rather than put on the terminal. I will now have to come up with a more elegant solution for that.

Anyway, this has solved the problem.

Comment: Yup, that's a consequence of the magic SDLmain has to do on Windows to somehow keep track of standard I/O but not pop up an annoying terminal window each time it's started.

Answer (score 2):

If you link with `libSDLmain`, or include `SDLMain.m`, your entry point will have to be named SDL_main instead:

```
extern "C" int SDL_main(int argc, char **argv)
{
}
```

(The `extern "C"` takes into account the fact that you are using C++.)

The "real" `main`, included in `libSDLmain` or `SDLMain.m`, makes the necessary Mac-specific preparations and then calls `SDL_main`.

Comment: Then why does my code compile when I link it with `libSDLMain.a`?

Comment: The `SDL_main.h` header contains a macro that renames your `main` function to `SDL_main`.

Answer (score 2):

There is a pure C solution to this as well: doing the compiler's work in lowering the Objective-C call to a C call, or a set of C calls.

```
#include <objc/runtime.h>
#include <objc/message.h>

static void createSharedApplication(void)
{
    id myNSApplication = objc_getClass("NSApplication");
    SEL mySharedApplication = sel_registerName("sharedApplication");
    id (*myMsgSend)(id, SEL) = (id (*)(id, SEL))objc_msgSend;

    myMsgSend(myNSApplication, mySharedApplication);
}
```

As you can see, however, this is not very elegant.